# Issue with uploading a JPEG, Google Drive saves it as a PNG

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I'm having an issue with uploading a photo to Google Drive via the SDK made available for Objective-C.

The summary of the situation is the following, I create a folder with a defined name, after the folder is created I upload a finite number of photos stores in my app. I wait until I receive confirmation that a photo was uploaded successfully before trying the next one on the list.

The issue I'm having is the following, I know the photo file is ~9MB, and it hits Google Drive successfully. The problem is that I'm uploading it with a MIME type image/jpeg, the file that actually appears in Google Drive is a PNG image file, and it's 22 MB in size!!!!!!! I can't understand why it's interpreting it as a PNG, and why does the size grow so much.

This is my relevant code:

```
- (void) uploadPhotoToFolder:(NSString *)identifier withIndex:(int)index{
        UIImage *content = [[photoArray objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *mimeType = @"image/jpeg";
        GTLDriveFile *metadata = [GTLDriveFile object];
        NSString *name =@"FileName";
        metadata.name = name;

        metadata.parents = @[identifier];

        NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(content);
        GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data
                                                                                     MIMEType:mimeType];
        GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesCreateWithObject:metadata
                                                           uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
        [self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                             GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                             NSError *error) {
            if (error == nil) {
                //Notify that upload was successful 
            }
            else {
                //Notify that upload failed.
            }

        }];
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(content);` which makes your image a PNG despite the MIME type you send.